# OpenCV throws errors after applying numpy transformations

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

I've run into a curious error. After applying `np.flip`, `cv2.rectangle` is throwing an error. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
image = np.random.choice(255,(50,50,3)).astype(np.uint8)
image_180 = np.flip(image.copy())
x1,y1,x2,y2 = 20,20,30,30
cv2.rectangle(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),1)
cv2.rectangle(image_180,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),1)
```

Both image and image_180 are of the type `numpy.ndarray`, and are of dtype `np.uint8`. However, the second call to rectangle throws the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Which makes no sense. I'm assuming this is a bug or something with a lazy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this error message is very confusing.

According to the official NumPy documentation, [`np.flip()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) returns a **view** of the input array. Presumably, this causes problems for OpenCV.

A simple fix is to pass a deep copy of the returned view, i.e.:

```
r = cv2.rectangle(image_180.copy(), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

Strangely enough, `cv2.rectangle()` does sometimes work with views, e.g.:

```
r = cv2.rectangle(image[:10], (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

This suggests to me there is some kind of a bug in either NumPy or OpenCV. Either way, using `.copy()` on your array will fix your issue.

Comment: You're right. I was doing a stop-gap fix by calling cv2.UMat(image_180).get(), but that is also effectively doing a deep copy as a part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

> image_180 = np.flip(image.copy())

your code is slightly confused (deep copy position),

below code works for me:

```
image_180 = np.flip(image).copy()
```